# How does other DNS servers (Googles Public DNS) know if you create a new record

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I am a but confused, I am looking into create a Public DNS server so that I could have a free domains apart from hosting because I manage a lot of domains. But I didn’t understand if someone who is not using my DNS server and lets say they are using Google’s. Google’s DNS server wouldn’t have my records therefore they couldn’t send the user to the right place. I don’t know if there is any way to get around this, i don’t know if it has something to do with glue record, I just heard of that. Is there like some registration thing were you register you DNS server. Or do I have to talk to main DNS providers to add my server as a secondary name server.

Thanks again.

Comment: You will need to learn first the difference between an authoritative nameserver (what you need to setup on your side) and recursive nameservers, such as Google Public DNS, and how they interact. This has nothing to do with glue records or secondary nameserver. I recommend you play with the DNS on your local servers with fake domains before using them for real, so that you can learn how it works.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Do you have Discord or something, because I would like to contact you and talk about how I would go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google and other public DNS resolvers (if your domain record you are requesting isn't already cached) will check your domain's name server from the domain, and then ask your nameserver for the IP address or domain record you requested.

Google or other DNS resolvers may temporarily cache it, but they won't store anything for extended periods of time because IPs on domains change often. You do not need to contact any DNS resolvers to store your domain name. As long as the correct name servers are showing in the `whois` of your domain, and your domain records are set up correctly, it should work fine.